# Ubuntu: BT headphones do not connect

Tags: bluetooth, headphones

I have a new pair of headphones. They are OneOdio Studio Wireless Y80B.

The BT device on my Ubuntu machines sees the headphones and is able to pair with them. Blueman shows they are *trusted*.

However, when I turn them on and hit connect, they connect briefly (a second), and then disconnect. When that happens, the headphones go into discovery mode and I can't even turn them off anymore (I had to plug them to the charger and unplug them).

Things I have tried/checked:

- Headphones work on Mac, iphone, and Ubuntu 21.10 they work.
- Headphones work on Galaxy Tab 2 running Android 4.2.2.
- BT device is 4.0-compatible as requested by headphone manufacturer.
- Using Ubuntu 18.04 or 20.04 makes no difference.
- Using Ubuntu on mac, or Ubuntu on dell computer makes no difference.
- Updating bluez to [5.50](https://launchpad.net/%7Ebluetooth/+archive/ubuntu/bluez) made no difference.
- Removing `/var/lib/bluetooth` made no difference.
- Removing `~/.config/pulse`, killing and restarting pulseaudio made no difference.
- Resetting the device made no difference.
- Charging the headphones all the way made no difference.

I don't know even how to begin to debug such a problem.

Comment: Personally the first thing I would do is check with the manufacture if they work on Ubuntu.

Comment: I don't think that'd be insightful. I've had about 6 pairs of headphones in the last 10 years. None of them "officially" worked on Ubuntu. If they say Ubuntu is not supported, like with many devices in Ubuntu, they might still work. Either way, I'm on my own.

Comment: Ubuntu is not supported, like with many devices in Ubuntu Your comment is totally off the wall.

Comment: Here: If Ubuntu is not "officially" supported, they might still work, like many devices still work in Ubuntu even though the manufacturer provides no support whatsoever and claims it is not supported.

Comment: New Info: they work in Ubuntu 21.10. So my problem now may be reduced to "how do I install bluez from source in an older Ubuntu".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a diagnosis of what happened, or a proper solution, just a workaround.

Whatever the problem was, it was apparently solved in a future version of one of the packages involved. I don't know which individual package needed updating. The collection of bluez/pulseaudio-related packages was too large to build everything from source.

Updating my OS to Ubuntu 21.10 made the headphones work.